# AS2 FLA Component with embeded classes

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, components

I'm trying to create an AS2 component which is easily skinnable.

I create an FLA component by creating a mc with some assets > component definition > link it to MyClass, and drop the fla into the Components dir.  If I then drag the component into a new fla and try to render, it obviously throws the error that it can't find MyClass.  I'd rather not provide the src files separately.

I've tried following some walk-throughs that described using the componentShim, but it seemed like that was only for AS3.

Any suggestions ?

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you're trying to create a compiled clip (SWC). You can find some Adobe documentation [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/mx2004/main_7_2/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Flash_MX_2004&file=00003108.html#1140637), but I'd rather go for [this tutorial](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?page=1&cid=DC2C0). Seems to be more straight forward and easier to understand.

Comment: you can't edit swc's content and skin it differently... so no, i'm actually looking for a way to do an fla component

Comment: Try to export a FLA component that will use the MyClass class from a swc component. Then you can ship both together. Won't that work?

Comment: If you mean to have 2 components, fla targeting the swc, then yea I'm sure it will work, but will require 2 components.   If you mean have a swc inside the fla component, well then thats what i'm trying to do but havn't been successful. I could be doing it wrong though ;/

Comment: I think you may need to create an mxp that places your swc in the proper folder of the Flash installation. See here: http://davidjmcclelland.com/eLearning/?p=196 for more details on creating an mxp